# Firebase REST api: orderBy 2 params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to order by 2 different params in firebase REST API and what's the correct api call should for that:

I need to get posts by userId and category. What's the correct endpoint should be for that?

```
 FIREBASE_URL/?orderBy="userId"&orderBy="category"&equalTo="${userId}"&equalTo=${category}`;

{
  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "todos": {
      ".indexOn": ["category", "userId"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't sort by multiple fields with Realtime Database.

Comment: So what can be a solution in this case? 2 API calls, one for sort by id, second one by category?

Comment: Click through to the marked duplicates for some alternatives.

Comment: @DougStevenson It doesn't my question at all

Comment: @drevival Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer in the question Doug linked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase